# How to reach Specific Node Tree's Features on Panel? (Bump, Image,..vs.)

Tags: python, interface, image

Hey guys I'm working on Material Management on 3D UI Panel.

But unfortunately I stuck somehow and don't find any answers:

How to reach a specific node tree's some vector or image features with name:

For Example:

```
node = node_tree.nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
                                
box.prop(node.inputs[0], "default_value")
box.prop(node.inputs[1], "default_value")
```

I can reach specific places, but cannot reach vectors

```
if image_node:
                                    # Display the image node using template_ID
                                    col.template_ID(image_node, "image", open='image.open')
                                    col.prop(image_node, "interpolation")
                                    col.prop(image_node, "projection")
                                    col.prop(image_node, "extension")
                                    if image_node.image:
                                     col.prop(image_node.image, "source")
                                     col.prop(image_node.image, "alpha_mode")
 
                                    if image_node.image:
                                        # Display the image texture node's properties
                                        #col.prop(image_node, "interpolation")
                                        #col.prop(image_node, "projection")
                                        #if bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].projection == 'BOX':
                                        obj = bpy.context.object
                                        material = obj.active_material
                                        if material.node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].projection == 'BOX':
                                            row= col.row()
                                            row.label(text="Blend :" )
                                            row.prop(image_node, "projection_blend", text="")
                                        
                                        #col.prop(image_node, "extension")
                                        #col.prop(image_node.image, "source")
                                        col.prop(image_node.image, "alpha_mode")
                                        
                                        #for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
                                        #    if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':  # Check if the node is an image texture node
                                        #        img_texture = node.image  # Access the image from the image texture node
                                        #        col.prop(img_texture, "alpha_mode")
                                                
        
                                        # Iterate through all images in bpy.data.images
                                        #for image in bpy.data.images:
                                        
                                        
                                        # Accessing the color space settings of the texture node
                                        color_space_settings = image_node.image.colorspace_settings
                                        col.prop(color_space_settings, "name" , text= "Color Space")
```

[image: As you can see I can't reach that values I have to write manually]

As you can see I can't reach that values I have to write manually.
And that's my problem.

If there any solutions out there?